CSS Grid area issue with React components
Even though I have set up the grid areas as shown below, the Cost Meter component is not appearing directly below the Electricity Meter as intended, and the alert now appearing on the right side. I am confused what is wrong with this grid box area.
The grid I am trying to achieve is fairly simple, but somehow isn't working.

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 918px 290px;
  grid-template-rows: 330px 270px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "electricity-meter alert-assist"
    "cost-meter alert-assist";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

const ElectricityMeterContainer = styled.div`
  grid-area: electricity-meter;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 918px;
  height: 330px;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const CostMeterContainer = styled.div`
  grid-area: cost-meter;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 918px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
`;

const AlertAssistContainer = styled.div`
  grid-area: alert-assist;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
`;

Components:
<DndContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
      <MainContainer>
        <SortableContext
          items={mainContainers.map((container) => container.id)}
          strategy={rectSortingStrategy}
        >
          {mainContainers.map((container) => (
            <SortableItem key={container.id} id={container.id}>
              {container.id === "electricity-meter-container" ? (
                <SortableContext
                  items={electricityComponents.map((component) => component.id)}
                  strategy={horizontalListSortingStrategy}
                >
                  <ElectricityMeterContainer>
                    {electricityComponents.map((component) => (
                      <SortableItem key={component.id} id={component.id}>
                        {component.content}
                      </SortableItem>
                    ))}
                  </ElectricityMeterContainer>
                </SortableContext>
              ) : container.id === "cost-meter-container" ? (
                <CostMeterContainer>
                  <CostMeterComponent />
                </CostMeterContainer>
              ) : container.id === "alert-assist-container" ? ( // Added condition here
                <AlertAssistContainer>
                  <AlertAssistComponent />
                </AlertAssistContainer>
              ) : null}
            </SortableItem>
          ))}
        </SortableContext>
      </MainContainer>
    </DndContext>[![enter image description here][1]][1]


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

At a quick glance I'd suggest the width of the alert div is the issue... 100%?

yes the alert div is the issue
